# 3D camera rotates the object, but not the camera in space. Implementation problem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, 3d, camera

I'm learning how to implement the 3D spaces. Now i want implement 3D camera for moving around my designed 3D space.
The problem is that camera rotate the 3D objects. But not the camera in space as need to be. I can not understand what i'm doing wrong.

Code of the `Camera` class:

```
public class Camera3D
    {
        public Vector3D Pos { get; set; }
        public Vector3D Target { get; set; }
        public Vector3D Up { get; set; }

        public double CameraSpeed { get; set; }


        public Camera3D(Vector3D pos, Vector3D target, Vector3D up)
        {
            Pos = pos;
            Target = target;
            Up = up;

            Pos.Normalize();
            Target.Normalize();
            Up.Normalize();
        }


        public Camera3D() 
        {
            Pos = new Vector3D(0, 0, 3);
            Target = new Vector3D(0, 0, 0);
            Up = new Vector3D(0, 1, 0);
        }

        private Vector3D GetCameraDirection(Vector3D pos, Vector3D target)
        {
            Vector3D dir = pos - target;
            dir.Normalize();
            return dir;
        }


        private Vector3D GetRight(Vector3D pos, Vector3D target, Vector3D up)
        {
            Vector3D right = Vector3D.CrossProduct(Up, GetCameraDirection(pos, up));
            right.Normalize();
            return right;
        }


        private Vector3D GetCameraUp(Vector3D pos, Vector3D target, Vector3D up)
        {
            Vector3D vup = Vector3D.CrossProduct(GetCameraDirection(pos, target), GetRight(pos, target, up));
            return vup;
        }


        public Matrix3D LookAt(Vector3D pos, Vector3D target, Vector3D up) 
        {
            // translation matrix for camera
            Matrix3D translation = new Matrix3D
                (
                1, 0, 0, -Pos.X,
                0, 1, 0, -Pos.Y,
                0, 0, 1, -Pos.Z,
                0, 0, 0, 1
                );


            Vector3D vRight = GetRight(pos, target, up);
            Vector3D vUp    = GetCameraUp(pos, target, up);
            Vector3D vDir   = GetCameraDirection(pos, target);
            Matrix3D m = new Matrix3D
                (
                    vRight.X,   vRight.Y,   vRight.Z,       0,
                    vUp.X,      vUp.Y,      vUp.Z,          0,
                    vDir.X,     vDir.Y,     vDir.Z,         0,
                    0,          0,          0,              1
                );

            return m * translation;
        }
    }
```

Some useful fields and constructor of main window

```
        // just temporary field for test rotating Camera
        double a = 0;

        Vector3D Translate = new Vector3D(1, 1, 1);
        Vector3D Rotation = new Vector3D(0, 0, 0);
        Vector3D Scaling = new Vector3D(1, 1, 1);

        CTransform3D cTransform; // class for transform operations
        Camera3D c = new Camera3D();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            cTransform = new CTransform3D(Rotation, Translate, Scaling);
            cTransform.Camera = c; // camera for transformations

            // load the mesh
            o.Mesh.LoadFromObjectFile("D:\\de\\test\\ship.obj");
        }
```

The main method that draw objects(here is all transformations, projection, and camera transformations too):

```
public void Draw()
        {
            try
            {
                // util classes
                MatrixUtil mu = new MatrixUtil();

                cv.Children.Clear(); // clear canvas

                foreach (var triangle in o.Mesh.Triangles)
                {
                   Triangle tProjected = new Triangle(), tTransformed = new Triangle(), tViewed = new Triangle();

                   // just init for right compile
                   tProjected.Points = new Vector3D[3] { new Vector3D(0, 0, 0), new Vector3D(0, 0, 0), new Vector3D(0, 0, 0) };
                   tTransformed.Points = new Vector3D[3] { new Vector3D(0, 0, 0), new Vector3D(0, 0, 0), new Vector3D(0, 0, 0) };
                   tViewed.Points = new Vector3D[3] { new Vector3D(0, 0, 0), new Vector3D(0, 0, 0), new Vector3D(0, 0, 0) };

                   // project and transform matrices
                   Matrix3D ProjectionMatrix = cTransform.ProjectionMatrix(5, Width, Height, 0.1, 1000); // just projection matrix
                   Matrix3D TransformMatrix = RotationMatrices.RotatationYMatrix(Rotation.Y); // rotate y
                   Matrix3D CameraMatrix = cTransform.GetCameraTransform(); // camera matrix that contains only LookAt
                   c.Pos = new Vector3D(Math.Sin(a), 0, Math.Cos(a)); // change position of camera


                   // transform points
                   tTransformed.Points[0] = mu.Matrix_MulVector(TransformMatrix, triangle.Points[0]);
                   tTransformed.Points[1] = mu.Matrix_MulVector(TransformMatrix, triangle.Points[1]); 
                   tTransformed.Points[2] = mu.Matrix_MulVector(TransformMatrix, triangle.Points[2]);

                   // multiple camera matrix to transformed points
                   tViewed.Points[0] = mu.Matrix_MulVector(CameraMatrix, tTransformed.Points[0]);
                   tViewed.Points[1] = mu.Matrix_MulVector(CameraMatrix, tTransformed.Points[1]); 
                   tViewed.Points[2] = mu.Matrix_MulVector(CameraMatrix, tTransformed.Points[2]);


                   // project the object
                   tProjected.Points[0] = mu.Matrix_MulVector(ProjectionMatrix, tViewed.Points[0]);
                   tProjected.Points[1] = mu.Matrix_MulVector(ProjectionMatrix, tViewed.Points[1]);
                   tProjected.Points[2] = mu.Matrix_MulVector(ProjectionMatrix, tViewed.Points[2]);
                  
                   // just draw the result
                   new CTriangle(
                        triangle.Points[0].X + o.Position.X, triangle.Points[0].Y + o.Position.Y ,
                        triangle.Points[1].X + o.Position.X, triangle.Points[1].Y + o.Position.Y ,
                        triangle.Points[2].X + o.Position.X, triangle.Points[2].Y + o.Position.Y ,
                        cv, Brushes.Gray, Brushes.Black);
                }

                a+= .1;

                Rotation.X += 0.05f;
                Rotation.Y += 0.05f;
                Rotation.Z += 0.05f;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Projection matrix method from `CTransform` class:

```
        public Matrix3D ProjectionMatrix(double fov, double width, double height, double near, double far)
        {
            int fAspectRatio = (int)(width / height);
            double fFovRad = 1.0f / Math.Tan(fov * 0.5f / 180.0f * 3.14159f);

            return new Matrix3D
                (
                fAspectRatio * fFovRad, 0, 0, 0,
                0, fFovRad, 0, 0,
                0, 0, far / (far - near), 1,
                0, 0, (-far * near) / (far - near), 1
                );
        }
```

`GetCameraTransform()` Method from `CTransform` class:

```
        public Matrix3D GetCameraTransform()
        {
            Matrix3D cameraLookAt = Camera.LookAt(camera.Pos, camera.Target, camera.Up);
            return cameraLookAt;
        }
```

Fields of camera from `CTransform` class:

```
        private Camera3D camera;
        public Camera3D Camera { get { return camera; } set { camera = value; } }
```

Multiple Matrix to Vector method from `MatrixUtil` class for transformations about points of triangle:

```
        public Vector3D Matrix_MulVector(Matrix3D m, Vector3D v)
        {
            Vector3D res = new Vector3D();

            // additional W component of vector usually will 1. So just add offsets
            res.X = v.X * m.M11 + v.Y * m.M21 + v.Z * m.M31 + m.OffsetX;
            res.Y = v.X * m.M12 + v.Y * m.M22 + v.Z * m.M32 + m.OffsetY;
            res.Z = v.X * m.M13 + v.Y * m.M23 + v.Z * m.M33 + m.OffsetZ;

            return res;
        }
```

I know its hard to understand all that mess. But i need help in understanding how the 3D camera works in 3D graphic. And how to implement it in my designed 3D space.

1. Tried change the order of multiplication matrix and triangles in all pipeline. Got more troubles.
2. Change the translation camera matrix. Result: nothing.
3. Change the `LookAt` method. Result: nothing.
4. Checked and tried to change some other matrices about transform the object. Result: nothing.

Comment: I think you should use a perspective camera. More xaml. Less code. Have you looked at the msdn examples? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-animate-camera-position-and-direction-in-a-3d-scene?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: This is interesting, i didn't looked that. But the main idea, is the implement all elements without using ready solutions. For full understanding 3D spaces.

Comment: Personally, I would start with something that works. Then change parts to explore what happens.